# Is there a way to render tiles on zoom stop?

Tags: mapbox-gl

When using `mapbox-gl`, is there a way to render the tiles when zooming stops? Now it renders all of the time which makes the app slow. I would like to be able to change the behaviour by loading the new tiles, when zooming stops...

So, when zooming in and out, nothing happens, but when I release, the new tiles load.

Example:
You see the behaviour when running the default example on your phone: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/. When you zoom in slowly, it renders the new tiles every step of the way. I would like to know of it’s possible to load the new tiles when you end the zoom (release fingers).

Comment: Could you add a code example as part of the question so that others may be able to help you out?

Comment: I've edited my question, it's default behaviour